# Entities and calculated properties

Tags: orm, domain-driven-design

What is the best practice to implement the following:

1. we have a classes `Order` and
   `OrderItem` as parent-child.
2. Class    `OrderItem` provides property `Cost`
3. On the OrdersList form we have to see    `MaxCost` column = max(cost)
   from `Items` collection

I found only one useful solution here which won't break the DDD concepts: to add a usual property `MaxCost` to the class `Order` and to update it each time when items list updates.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, but you have to ask yourself "why?".  From the standpoint of the domain, does it "care" if you are recomputing this repeatedly?  Or are you letting programmer-domain creep into your problem domain?

One other thing --- consider making "max cost of items" part of the collection of OrderItems, and hiding HOW you get it from the rest of the system.